# ping: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: ubuntu, dns, ping

I tried speeding up DNS lookup in Ubuntu 17.04 and followed the instructions from the second post here: [Ubuntu 17.04 systemd-resolved DNS lookups randomly fail](https://superuser.com/questions/1153203/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-resolved-dns-lookups-randomly-fail)

Result: once I reboot name resolution does not work at all:

```
ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Everything works after I type

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

How to fix this? Having to type this command after each reboot is less than ideal.

Comment: This is how I solved it for a `debootstrap` setup: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045278/ubuntu-server-18-04-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution/1080902#1080902

Answer (score 1):

Posts are ordered by rank, so the "second post" could change over time. It appears it hasn't though and assuming you indeed followed instructions from:

https://superuser.com/a/1154386/293731

Then in the instructions you *disabled* systemd-resolved so it no longer starts automatically at boot. Just run this command and reboot, it should work again:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
```