# Browsers do not load pages unless routed through TOR on one of my computers. Even across different operating systems. Other computer works fine

Tags: linux, dns, tor, ubuntu-20.04

On my HP laptop I have Ubuntu 20.x installed and everything worked fine until yesterday. Firefox wouldn't load pages anymore, but TOR bundle browser did.

I cannot ping google.com but I can ping 8.8.8.8

So I thought it must be some DNS issue but couldn't figure it out, so I installed another linux distro. For an hour everything worked fine and now I have *the exact same problem* on that distro.

I have restarted the router but nothing changed.

On the machine I am currently at (a Chromebook running Gallium OS) everything is fine. Both machines connect to the same router via WLAN.

What could possibly be the problem that replicates on two separate operating systems? Malware acting on a low level?
I use the machine for cyber security experimentation. I download and install stuff liberally, but not stupidly. However, I am still new to all of this stuff so maybe I messed up?

Are there any other explanations? My ISP or router blocking traffic from that machine because its flagged as a threat maybe? The day before I experimented with `sendemail` and tried e-mail spoofing by trying to send a spoofed e-mail to myself. Not actually doing anything criminal or illegal.

Comment: ”Firefox wouldn't load pages anymore, but TOR bundle browser did.” Sounds like a a routing table issue. Check the contents of `/etc/resolver/` like this: `ls -la /etc/resolver/`.

Comment: Neither OS seems to have an /etc/resolver directory. Only a file called resolv.conf in the /etc directory which says "This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit." and something about it possibly being a symlink.

Comment: Look at the answers [here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1243114) as well as [here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1153203/167207). Heck, check out [this answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1272389/51813). The core suggestion of reinstalling the DNS solver might help: `apt install --reinstall resolvconf network-manager libnss-resolve`

Comment: Yes, I could have been a little more pro-active with your answer. Editing /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and adding

[Resolve] 
DNS=192.168.2.1 solved it. I have no idea why, but oh well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and adding  `[Resolve] DNS=192.168.2.1` solved it.